# How to make a rich tooltip with a HTML form in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a paragraph of text with a link in it. I want to make a rich tool tip with a title on the top and a field to collect email addresses appear on hovering the link. What approach should I take?

I have looked into tool tip libraries but none seem to have form support. Please find the code below

The content in which the link is present:

```
<p>Pellentesque habitant <a href="#">Link to show tooltip</a> morbi senectus  
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada pellentesque habitant senectus 
fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies  
eget,  tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.  
Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

Tool tip content:

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <h3>Tooltip title</h3>
  <p>Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies  
  eget,  tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.  
  Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="john@doe.com" />
    <input type="submit" value="subscribe" />
  </form>
  <span class="branding">This is our branding message</span>
</div>
```

Now the effect I want to achieve is when I hover the link in the content the tooltip content should appear in a styled div. How should I do it?

Comment: Sounds bad for accessibility, some people can't use the mouse very well, and they would need to keep the mouse over the hovered element whilst moving straight up to the tooltip. Also, will it work on touch devices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this snippet

**Updated**

```js
$("a").bind("mousemove", function(event) {
    $("div.tooltip").css({
        top: event.pageY + 10 + "px",
        left: event.pageX + 10 + "px"
    }).show();
})
$('.close').bind('click', function(){
  $("div.tooltip").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
}
.tooltip {
    width:350px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:#CB5757;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid #AB4141;
    padding:15px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px #8D8D8D;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.close{
  right: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  color: #555;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<p>Pellentesque habitant <a href="#">Link to show tooltip</a> morbi senectus  
    tristique senectus et netus et malesuada pellentesque habitant senectus 
    fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies  
    eget,  tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.  
    Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
</p>
<div class="tooltip">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <h3>Tooltip title</h3>
    <p>Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies  
        eget,  tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.  
        Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
    </p>
    <form>
        <input type="email" placeholder="john@doe.com" />
        <input type="submit" value="subscribe" />
    </form>
    <span class="branding">This is our branding message</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you move the mouse into the tooltip to enter the data?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Add the link and the tooltip div inside a new div.
2. Set tooltip div property to be visibility: hidden;
3. and on hover set the property of this tooltip to be visible.

like:
HTML:

```
<div class="link"> <a href="#">Link to show tooltip</a> 
<div class="tooltip"> ......</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.link {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.link .tooltip {
visibility: hidden;
width: 120px;
background-color: black;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 5px 0;

position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}

.link:hover .tooltip {
visibility: invisible;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try to display yout tooltip element with the tilde selector on link hover:

```
.tooltip { 
  display: none; 
} 

a:hover ~ .tooltip{ 
  display: block; 
}
```

And then place your tooltip after the link element.

```
<p>
  blabla
  <a href="#">hover me</a>
  <span class="tooltip">tooltip content</span>
  blabla
</p>
```

Here a [pen](http://codepen.io/p1n5u/pen/gwpPYy) where it works

Comment: Did you test this yourself before posting it?